# Does Azure RateCard REST API cater price changes?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-cloud-services

Does Azure RateCard REST API include information about price changes?

For example, if the price changed in June 2016, is there a way to find out both the old and new prices for a particular meter?

There is an `EffectiveDate` attribute but I haven't seen a case where there are multiple attributes with this name to indicate price change.

Answer (score 0):

Azure RateCard Rest API is still in preview. We can use this API to get meter  metadata information along with price, as I know, it does not support show old price for a particular meter. please submit this voice at Azure feedback forum.